Unable to Load and Predict with Keras Model After Upgrading tensorflow
I was saving my Keras model using the following code:
inputs = keras.Input(shape=(1,), dtype="string")
processed_inputs = text_vectorization(inputs)
outputs = model(processed_inputs)
inference_model = keras.Model(inputs, outputs)

After upgrading Tensorflow, I am unable to load the model and make predictions on a DataFrame. My current code for loading the model and predicting is as follows:
loaded_model = load_model('model.keras')
load_LE = joblib.load('label_encoder.joblib')

input_string = "i just usit for nothin"
xd = pd.DataFrame({'Comentario': [input_string]})

preddict = loaded_model.predict(xd['Comentario'])

predicted_clasess = preddict.argmax(axis=1)
xd['Prediccion'] = load_LE.inverse_transform(predicted_clasess)

However, I am encountering the following error:
object of type 'bool' has no len()

List of objects that could not be loaded:
[<TextVectorization name=text_vectorization, built=True>, <StringLookup name=string_lookup_2, built=False>]

Details:
- The error occurs when attempting to load the model and predict on a DataFrame.
- The model includes a TextVectorization layer and a StringLookup layer.

Any advice or insights would be greatly appreciated!
UPDATE:
On the same notebookthat i trained the model i can make predictions:
raw_text_data = tf.convert_to_tensor([
    ["That was an excellent movie, I loved it."],
])
predictions = inference_model(raw_text_data)
predictions

But if i try to load the model on another notebook i get:
[<TextVectorization name=text_vectorization, built=True>, <StringLookup name=string_lookup_9, built=False>]

UPDATE2: I tried to reinstall the earlier version but the problem its the same
